# BufferedReader.readLine() always throws IOException but only with a real smartphone

Tags: java, android, bufferedreader, readline, ioexception

buffered reader always throws IOException, thanks for your help!

You all reading: try checking if you preclosed your connection classes.

check it even if in your sdk everything works fine

Comment: Please write your error log statements like this: Log.e("json","ioExc. reading line from buffered reader", e); instead of writing the stack trace with e.printStackTrace(). This way you get the stack trace and exception message to the Android log. The message especially is vital to debugging this. Also, the value returned from a constructor is absolutely never null. You either get an object or an exception is thrown. And finally Apache IOUtils, among many others, provides a readFully method so you don't really need to write the loop yourself. :)

Comment: OK i'll make the changes, give me some minutes

Comment: `inputStream` What is inputStream? Please show complete code. We cant even see which component you use. Or if you posted something.

Comment: `greenapps requested the inputStream code:` No. I requested all code. urlConnection and more. The complete code. I weanna see what you do. Or eventuallay try your code. Then i need to copy/paste all.

Comment: `Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this.context.getApplicationContext(), "Seems like login is required to navigate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);` You cannot have a Toast() there as you are not on the main thread here.

Comment: `This takes place before the code i wrote before` Well put it before then also. Post complete code.

Comment: ok, ill do my best

Comment: `think the problem is managing readline with lollipop` There is nothing special with readLine() in Lollipop.

Comment: `inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());` and `BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));` You buffer too much. Do away with that extra variable inputStream.

Comment: I'm taking notes of everytigh you are writing, i'll look for lighter buffering (this was the only way i knew). in a while you will have the complete 2 functions that make connection, just wait until i'll rewrite in english the comments. i use my native language to differentiate from the android logs

Comment: `catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("URL json taker","Fail openConnection.");` Nearly everywhere you are throwing away valuable info about the caus of an exception. Better: `catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d(TAG, "IOException: " + e.getMessage());`.

Comment: do you think i should use e.getmessage() for logs in codes i already know how they works, replacing the e.printStacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
   } finally {
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
```

You closed the connection.

So no wonder a following read will not do.

Comment: OH that it was! thanks! then why on the sdk everything worked fine?

Comment: That is hard to believe.

Comment: i'll make a gif if you don't believe me :D seriously i was happy before takeng a real device because everything worked fine. however thanks. everytime use a real phone is better.  i found this a while ago because i was trying to change text color of the activity but ended with a listview in white while the rest in black, and only on real device (the sdk made all black)

Comment: Nothing beats a real device. Even if it runs Lollipop. ;-).